# PhusionPassenger : Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I am new to rails developer,I have deploy rails application on my server. But now it is not started and giving error on browser as below :

### Error message:

```
There was an error while trying to write to Gemfile.lock. It is likely that you need to allow write permissions for the file at path: /var/www/PCMI/zil/Gemfile.lock (Bundler::InstallError)
```

### Exception class:

```
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
```

### Application root:

```
/var/www/PCMI/zil
```

### Backtrace:

```
0  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/       bundler/definition.rb  238  in `rescue in lock'

1  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb 223     in `lock'

2   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/environment.rb   39  in `lock'

3   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb   39  in `setup'

4   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler.rb   116     in `setup'

5   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb    326     in `prepare_app_process'

6   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb     156     in `block in initialize_server'

7   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb    563     in `report_app_init_status'

8   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb     154     in `initialize_server'

9   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  204     in `start_synchronously'

10  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  180     in `start'

11  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb     129     in `start'

12  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    253     in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'

13  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   132     in `lookup_or_add'

14  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    246     in `block in spawn_rack_application'

15  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   82  in `block in synchronize'

16  < td=""> <> prelude>    10:in `synchronize'

17  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   79  in `synchronize'

18  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    244     in `spawn_rack_application'

19  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    137     in `spawn_application'

20  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    275     in `handle_spawn_application'

21  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  357     in `server_main_loop'

22  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  206     in `start_synchronously'

23  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@domain_name/gems/passenger-3.0.17/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server     99  in `'
```

Please check error displayed into browser.Please help me for my problem.
Thanks.

Comment: `bundle install` runs with super user permissions only of you have ones. Also try deleting the `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle update`

Comment: I try to run bundle update after delete Gemfile.lock But it gives error : //lib/ld-linux.so.2: could not read symbols: Memory exhausted
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [init.so] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/therubyracer-0.11.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/therubyracer-0.11.3/ext/v8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.11.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.3'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.3'  I run this command and gives error Error installing therubyracer:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@openmunicipalities.org/gems/therubyracer-0.11.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@openmunicipalities.org/gems/therubyracer-0.11.3/ext/v8/gem_make.out

Comment: Thats ok. `therubyracer` gem requires a JS runtime installed. It uses the Google's `libv8`, so make sure you have that installed.

Comment: i run 'gem install libv8' and it installed properly. then i run 'gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.3'' again. bt it throws same error.

Comment: `libv8` is a library. Install it by running `sudo apt-get install libv8-dev` (on Ubuntu). Or it could be achieved simply by installing [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/). That will install `libv8` and all it's requirements.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libv8-dev this command gives error : Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe libv8-2.2.18 i386 2.2.18-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe libv8-dev i386 2.2.18-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libv/libv8/libv8-2.2.18_2.2.18-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like passenger can't write to the lock file for your gem file. Basically it can't be sure your not running bundled because it can't get an exclusive lock on that file.

Make sure the user passenger is running under (apache defaults to www-data) has write permission on that file.

You can do this by using `chown` and `chmod`

Comment: Does bundle install work when your run it from the terminal? And can you run rails s without issues?

Comment: and rails s also work properly. bt when i run rails s it increased error in browser. it tell for install postgresql. But i had install it early. when i install it error in browser are same as in question.

Comment: If you aren't super worried about getting newer versions of gems you can delete the Gemfile.lock and then run bundle install to let bundler re create it.