# Cannot bundle install because of permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions

When I update my Gemfile and run `bundle install`, it comes up with the error message

```
There was an error while trying to write to Gemfile.lock. It is likely that you need to allow write permissions for the file at path: /var/www/archive/Gemfile.lock
```

So I do `sudo bundle install`. Now it says

```
sudo: bundle: command not found
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: What did you add to your Gemfile?

Comment: I added `gem 'therubyracer'`

Comment: Hmm.. It seems that someone else experienced a similar issue with that gem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018351/phusionpassenger-ruby-rack-application-could-not-be-started